# What can be wrong with word count program?

Tags: perl, testing, count, cpu-word

I've got a question in my test:

> What is wrong with program that counts number of lines and words in file?

```
open F, $ARGV[0] || die $!;
my @lines = <F>;
my @words = map {split /\s/} @lines;
printf "%8d %8d\n", scalar(@lines), scalar(@words);
close(F);
```

My conjectures are:

1. If file does not exist, program won't tell us about that.
2. If there are punctuation signs in file, program will count them, for example, in

   > ```
   > abc cba
   > , , ,dce
   > ```

   will be five word, but on the other hand `wc` outputs the same result, so it might be considered as correct behavior.
3. If `F` is a large file, it might be better to iterate over lines and not to dump it into `lines` array.

Do you have any less trivial ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the first line, you have a precedence problem:

```
open F, $ARGV[0] || die $!;
```

is the same as

```
open F, ($ARGV[0] || die $!);
```

which means the `die` is executed if the filename is false, not if the `open` fails.  You wanted to say

```
open(F, $ARGV[0]) || die $!;
```

or

```
open F, $ARGV[0] or die $!;
```

Also, you should be using the 3 argument form of open, in case `$ARGV[0]` contains characters that mean something to `open`.

```
open F, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
```

On a different note, splitting on `/\s/` means that you get a "word" between consecutive whitespace characters.  You probably meant `/\s+/`, or as amphetamachine suggested, `/\W+/`, depending on how you want to define a "word".

That still leaves the problem of the empty "word" you get if the line begins with whitespace.  You could split on `' '` to suppress that (it's a special case), or you could trim leading whitespace first, or insert a `grep { length $_ }` to weed out empty "words", or abandon `split` and use a different method for counting words.

Processing line by line instead of reading the whole file at once would also be a good improvement, but it's not as important as those first two items.

Comment: Thank you, I think, precedence problem is the answer for that question.

Answer (score 3):

- <strike>Your conjecture #1 is incorrect: your program will die if the `open` fails.</strike> (see cjm's answer re order of operations.)
- you're using a global filehandle, rather than a lexical variable.
- you're not using the three-argument form of `open`.
- you could just read from stdin, which gives more flexibility as to input - the user can provide a file, or pipe the input into stdin.
- lastly, I wouldn't write my own code to parse words; I'd reach for CPAN, say something like [Lingua::EN::Splitter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Lingua%3a%3aEN%3a%3aSplitter).

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Lingua::EN::Splitter qw(words);
my ($wordcount, $lines);
while (<>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    $lines++;
    $wordcount += scalar(words $line);
}

printf "%8d %8d\n", $lines, $wordcount;
```

Comment: No, it will die if the filename is false.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you `open F, $ARGV[0] || die $!` that will effectively exit if the file doesn't exist.

There are some improvements to be made here:

```
{local $/; $lines = <F>;} # read all lines at once

my @words = split /\W+/, $lines;
```